# Prove or disprove that the series is converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to prove or disprove the following statement -

If $a_{n} >= 0 ,  p > 1$ , and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty{a_{n}}$  converge , then $\sum_{i=1}^\infty{a_{n}^p}$ converge

Well , It looks like a wrong statement but I couldn't think about familiar counterexample.
I would like to get a hint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Prove that eventually $a_n < 1$, after which ${a_n}^p \le a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is true. Since $\sum a_n$ converges and $a_n\ge0$ we have
$$\lim_n a_n=0.$$
This implies that exists $N>0$ such that $0\le a_n\le1$ for every $n>N$. Thus
$$\sum_{n\ge N}a_n^p\le\sum_{n\ge N}a_n$$
and the statement is proved.

Comment: I've no idea what this answer got downvoted whereas the other one got upvoted: they both say the same!